# Uniform integrability of martingale projection

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$ is a martingale relative to a filtration $(F_t)$ and that $(G_t)$ is a sub-filtration of $F$. Define a new martingale $Y$ by $Y_t := E(X_t | G_t) $.

Question: does "$Y$ is uniformly integrable" imply "$X$ is uniformly integrable"?

Many thanks.

Comment: Well, in general not... just consider the trivial filtration $\mathcal{G}_t := \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.

Comment: Thanks @saz. I knew that was wishful thinking. I've now asked the full question that motivated the one above
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551053/exponential-martingales-and-changes-of-measure

Answer (score 1):

As saz pointed out, the answer is no. If $\mathcal{G}_t := \left\{\emptyset,\Omega\right\}$, then $Y_t=\mathbb E\left[X_t\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_0\right]$ whatever the martingale $X$ is. In particular, $X$ may not be uniformly integrable.